# Changing (or just inverting) Basemap Colors in QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, color, stamen

I am building a vector (strava routes) map using QGIS and the Stamen Toner OSM Basemaps but want to edit it to change the colors of the baseman slightly. Is this possible? I see Arc seems to have a beta feature but not sure if there's a way to do so in QGIS. Is the basemap essentially just an image?

If easier, I've found the Stamen Toner map inverted is essentially exactly what I want (white streets on dark background). So I've been building the map in QGIS with my computer colors inverted, is there an easy way to just do that that wouldn't involve manually changing colors?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you need "white streets on dark background"?

Comment: Yes, I definitely want white streets on dark background but I'm trying to make some wall art out of it so would love to be able to play around with the colors more than just that if possible!

Comment: Follow up question: is adjusting (removing) the labels on a basemap out of the question?

Comment: `Stamen Toner Backgroud` is unlabeled version. then you can add `Stamen Toner Label` individually.

Answer (score 4):

Using **QuickMapServices** plugin, add the basemap you mentioned. (`Web Menu > QuickMapServices > Search QMS`, search `Stamen Toner Background` and add it)

- Open `Layer Properties > Symbology`.
- Set `Blending Mode` to `Diference`.

[image]

Comment: Oh sweet, so it is much easier to just invert, thank you! Istanbul looks great on that baseman

Comment: Ah, figured it out, adding a hue in the same menu works!

Answer (score 2):

Different and more beautiful solution would be like that:

- Add a new polygon layer
- Add a polygon covering all the wolrd
- Open `Layer Properties > Symbology > Layer options`
- Try different `Blending Options`.

[image]